# Ordinary Differential Equations self-study reference request

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I know there are a lot of reference requests for differential equations textbooks but none seem to be what I need. I'm looking for a book I can use for self study that isn't overly complicated and explains a lot (meaning it doesn't often say "left as an exercise for the reader" but instead proves all major results). I have taken mutlivariable calculus and am currently taking linear algebra so I also need a book that assumes no prior knowledge/experience with differential equations. If possible I'd prefer a book that explains the reasons for doing things and not just the methods. Thanks in advance. (If there is another question that I missed that asks for all these criteria please let me know and I'll see if those are what I'm looking for.)

Comment: An introductory text that is very careful with correct and precise statements and justifications, but which isn't an upper-level "ODE theory text", is [**Differential Equations**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002C9EH2E) by Ralph Palmer Agnew. This book is also very well written and it is even quite humorous in places.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Adkins and Davidson ODE textbook?  [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1461436176](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461436176)  I think it's a good choice for self-study -- the text is clear, there are solutions to the odd-numbered exercises, and it introduces the Laplace transform early on. Believe me, the Laplace transform is your friend. Plus, if you have access to a university library, you may have access to the electronic version of this textbook for free via SpringerLink.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Elementary Differential Equations](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4258454-elementary-differential-equations) by Earl D. Rainville and Phillip E. Bedient.

> A clear, concise book that emphasizes finding solutions to differential equations where applications play an important role. Each chapter includes many illustrative examples to assist the reader. The book emphasizes methods for finding solutions to differential equations. It provides many abundant exercises, applications, and solved examples with careful attention given to readability. *Elementary Differential Equations* includes a thorough treatment of power series techniques. In addition, the book presents a classical treatment of several physical problems to show how Fourier series become involved in the solution of those problems. The eighth edition of *Elementary Differential Equations* has been revised to include a new supplement in many chapters that provides suggestions and exercises for using a computer to assist in the understanding of the material in the chapter. It also now provides an introduction to the phase plane and to different types of phase portraits. A valuable reference book for readers interested in exploring the technological and other applications of differential equations.