# Rigorous math books with informal comments

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for math books that have informal comments.
Personally, I always find such comments to be entertaining.

An example of such a book is *Differential Equations and Their Applications* by *Martin Braun*.
It's rigorous, like any other math book. It's not a book about pop-math. At some point, it tells the story of Tacoma Narrows Bridge.

Comment: In Vakil's The Rising Sea, he tells jokes.

Comment: I know your question isn't restricted to ODE texts, but since you asked, I recommend you looking at [**Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002C9EH2E) by Ralph Palmer Agnew (1960). See my comments about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249939/13130) and [review in **Mathematics Magazine**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2689330) and [review in **American Mathematical Monthly**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2309273).

Comment: The book "Proofs A Long-Form Mathematics Textbook" by Jay Cummings, contains such comments. It has a nice sence of humor. Also it is relatively cheap for a math book.